# how to make two columns with different background and left right spacing in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to make website topbar like this image:
[image]

1st column should have color-1. 
2nd column should have color-2
between these columns there should be angle.

So I tried like this:

**Here is HTML code:**

```
<section class="topbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 left">
        <p>Welcome to Remote Auto Diagnostics</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 right">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Here is CSS:**

```
.topbar {
    background: #f41004;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.topbar .left {
    background: #00f;
}

.topbar .left:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200%;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    top: -10px;
    transform: skew(-45deg);
}
```

**It gives result like this:** 
[image]

As you can see there is left and right padding because of the container and the .topbar background is displaying. How to make .left background color start from left.

when I use container-fluid, container left and right padding removes, like this:

[image]

Comment: I messed around with this a bit. It's going to get weird when you resize your window the way you are trying to do it. Bootstrap will functionally shift the right section down and will place right below the blue section.

Comment: we should manage it from media screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used different approach: instead of using `:after` and skew that content, I just directly skew the "left" with the blue background, and skew "left"'s content back.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/81233/

#### HTML

```
<section class="topbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="skewed">
                    <div class="content">
                        Welcome to Remote Auto Diagnostics
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                Menu
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

#### CSS

```
.topbar {
    background: #f41004;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 2rem;
}

.topbar .skewed {
    background-color: #00f;
    transform: skew(-45deg);
    margin-left: -2rem;  /* this offset margin-left = padding-left */
}

.topbar .skewed .content {
    padding-left: 2rem;  /* this padding-left = offset margin-left */
    transform: skew(45deg);
}
```

#### Result

[image]

**Note:** I assume you don't want the skew effect on small screens. So I would suggest, instead of using built-in container, row and col, you might just style the topbar directly using flex-box so that you have more controls.

Comment: You did right job, I have tried this too. But the problem is the container of the website is 1440px. and for this topbar I need to have blue background in left, red background in right. but the text should be within 1440px; Here is my problem: https://imgur.com/uKhpfT9

Comment: Sure, but what happens on smaller screens? You want the left and the right stack up? Otherwise @caiovisk's answer is good. You just use gradient for the topbar's background color, and use your `container` instead of `container-fluid`.

Comment: On smaller screens, I think, we should manage manually via media screens. isn't it?

Comment: Yes but I am asking you what do you want on smaller screens? because @caiovisk's post should be the answer if you want the background stays like that (half blue half red). You just need to use `container` instead of `container-fluid` for your problem. But if you want the left and right stack up, for example, blue being its own row and red being its own row, then we have some more work to do. I still think that could be achieved by @caiovisk's approach too.

Comment: Thank you so much. I used container and for smaller screens I used media screens to manage everything. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a css gradient: https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

`background: linear-gradient(135deg, blue 50%, red 50%);`

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.topbar {
    /*background: #f41004;*/
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, blue 50%, red 50%);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.topbar .left {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="topbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-xs-6 left">
        <p>Welcome to Remote Auto Diagnostics</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-xs-6 right">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: your solution is good. but it's not the answer to my problem: here is my problem https://imgur.com/uKhpfT9

Comment: if you do not want the whole content to go wide you should use `.container` instead `.container-fluid`... Can you explain your problem better?